# Error in open.connection(x,"rb") : HTTP error 406

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest, http-status-code-406

I am trying to read the contents of a website using `read_html`in R. However, for some websites like `http://benchmarkrealestate.com/`, I get this error. `Error in open.connection(x,"rb") : HTTP error 406`

What does this error mean? This only happens in some websites. I tried to look it up online, but wasn't able to find the exact reason why I get this error.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain just what parts of which explanation weren't clear? Also, perhaps include the code you're ostensibly using?

Comment: @hrbrmstr, the code I was using was just `read_html(http://benchmarkrealestate.com/)` . Abdou's answer was helpful to solve the problem. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 406 Not Acceptable

> The requested resource is capable of generating only content not
> acceptable according to the Accept headers sent in the request.

The sentence above is lifted right off of Wikipedia.

Basically, whenever a Web crawler makes a request to a website, it often identifies itself, its application type and other information by submitting a characteristic identification string to its operating peer, i.e. the web server. In this case, this identification is transmitted in a header field called ***User-Agent***.

One way to have the content of the web page returned to your console is to set your ***user-agent*** information to something identifiable with the help of the `curl` package:

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
library(curl)

web_content <- read_html(curl('http://benchmarkrealestate.com/', handle = new_handle("useragent" = "Mozilla/5.0")))
```

You may also want to read up on [header fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).

Comment: Great! Thank you. This was very helpful. :)